# What is this bush/shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image]

The bush/shrub is about 7' tall and 10' wide. It blooms in april. I have not noticed any berries.  It is in North east Wyoming.[image][image]

Comment: If its got dark leaves, its Prunus cerasifera

Comment: @Bamboo I was thinking along the same lines, but if you look very closely, you'll see tiny bright green leaves.

Comment: @Stephie aye, but the basic plant has  green leaves, which I should have clarified - the one with dark leaves is Prunus cerasifera 'nigra'. Also, leaves on many dark leaved plants may start out green, but turn dark as they get larger, with exposure to light.

Answer (score 6):

Without details like leaves, bark and overall growth habit, the *precise* id is very difficult, but it's almost certainly a member of the **[prunus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus)** family.
All of them have similar blossom structures and are in the white to dark pink color range.

Some of the most prominent members are fruiting trees, e.g. plums, cherries, almonds, peaches.
Others are bred for their decorative properties, the first example that comes to mind is probably the [Japanese cherry,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serrulata) which influenced a whole [culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanami).

With fruit, an id would be quick, but some decorative breeds rarely set fruit and even for the fruiting kinds, one late frost or bad weather during the blooming period can leave you with nothing. But perhaps you could have a closer look? (Although cherries would be long gone by now.)

Comment: It doesn't have fruit. I will try to get more info

Comment: What a great mystery this is -- and without murder, mayhem or other violence:  Cherry? ... Wouldn't any kind of cherry (flowering or other) have its flowers borne on long stems, and not so close set onto the branch?

Comment: @LorelC. My first thought was „plum“, but since OP has added a picture of the *leaves*, I need to rethink.

Answer (score 3):

Agree on prunus. And

It looks *exactly* like an apricot to me.

Looking on the internet, apparently it is *possible* to have an apricot tree that won't fruit due to lack of nutrients, pollination or other reason. Hard to believe I guess, ... but REALLY looks like an apricot; beautiful photo, by the way.

Try checking the leaves. Apricot leaves are bright green, broad and pointy:

[image: apricot leaves]

Picture from https://www.healthbenefitstimes.com/apricots/

Answer (score 1):

Good morning!  Thank you for the idea of a Prunus. I looked up Prunus Bush and looked at the images. I found it! The Bush is called a Prunus tomentosa!! Non fruit baring.